# Running Say Command When Mac Is Logged Out

Tags: terminal

What would happen if I (remotely) ran a `say` command on a Mac that's logged out? Would the command run? Or wait until the user logs in to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would either have to wake the computer first, or you'd be locked out if the settings in system preferences disallowed you from such a thing.

Comment: Is it possible that it would screw up the system at startup? Or make apps crash?

Comment: It depends. If you designed it to do so, or coded it so, then perhaps. Just running it as you've described would not cause any errors or 1st party apps to crash.

Comment: Good to hear. Thank you! I can't give you an upvote yet or click the checkmark. I really appreciate your answers.

Comment: @FrankDraws you can now